# Synchronization of Multithreading in C accross multiple program

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

I have written a code using Pthreads condition variables. The main thread creates three threads.  Two of those threads increment a "count" variable, while the third thread watches the value of "count".  When "count"  reaches a predefined limit (10), the waiting thread is signaled by one of the incrementing threads. The waiting thread "awakens" and then modifies count. The program continues until the incrementing threads reach TCOUNT (20). The main program prints the final value of count. Here execution of two threads are alternating . I have checked with 5 threads also and it is working fine.

Now I want to do the same with parallel along with new program2. Here other program2 will ONLY access the shared variable, print the value ,but will not modify the value. Is mutex locking like ret = pthread_mutexattr_setpshared(&mattr, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED) will serve my purpose ? How to use mutex in program2 ?

**Here is my program( first.c)**

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NUM_THREADS  3
#define TCOUNT 10
#define COUNT_LIMIT2 20


int     count = 0;
pthread_mutex_t count_mutex;
pthread_cond_t count_threshold_cv;

void *inc_count(void *t)
{
    int i;
    long my_id = (long)t;

    for (i=0; i < TCOUNT; i++)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&count_mutex);
        count++;

        /*
         Check the value of count and signal waiting thread when condition is
         reached.  Note that this occurs while mutex is locked.
         */
        if ( count == COUNT_LIMIT2)
        {
            printf("%d- inc_count(): thread %ld, count = %d  Threshold reached. ",i,
                   my_id, count);
            pthread_cond_signal(&count_threshold_cv);
            printf("Just sent signal.\n");

        }
        printf("%d- inc_count(): thread %ld, count = %d, unlocking mutex\n", i,
               my_id, count);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&count_mutex);

        /* Do some work so threads can alternate on mutex lock */
        sleep(1);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void *watch_count(void *t)
{
    long my_id = (long)t;

    printf("Starting watch_count(): thread %ld\n", my_id);

    /*
     Lock mutex and wait for signal.  Note that the pthread_cond_wait routine
     will automatically and atomically unlock mutex while it waits.
     Also, note that if COUNT_LIMIT is reached before this routine is run by
     the waiting thread, the loop will be skipped to prevent pthread_cond_wait
     from never returning.
     */
    pthread_mutex_lock(&count_mutex);
    while (count < COUNT_LIMIT2)
    {
        printf("watch_count(): thread %ld Count= %d. Going into wait...\n", my_id,count);
        pthread_cond_wait(&count_threshold_cv, &count_mutex);
        printf("watch_count(): thread %ld Condition signal received. Count= %d\n", my_id,count);
        printf("watch_count(): thread %ld Updating the value of count...\n", my_id,count);
        //count += 125;
        printf("watch_count(): thread %ld count now = %d.\n", my_id, count);
    }
    printf("watch_count(): thread %ld Unlocking mutex.\n", my_id);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&count_mutex);
    /* Do some work so threads can alternate on mutex lock */
    sleep(1);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i, rc;
    long t[NUM_THREADS];

    for(i=0;i<NUM_THREADS;i++)
        t[i]=i+1;


    pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
    pthread_attr_t attr;

    /* Initialize mutex and condition variable objects */
    pthread_mutex_init(&count_mutex, NULL);
    pthread_cond_init (&count_threshold_cv, NULL);

    /* For portability, explicitly create threads in a joinable state */
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);

    for(i=0;i<NUM_THREADS;i++)
    {
        if(i==0)
            pthread_create(&threads[i], &attr, watch_count, (void *)t[i]);
        else
            pthread_create(&threads[i], &attr, inc_count, (void *)t[i]);
    }
    /* Wait for all threads to complete */
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++) {
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    }
    printf ("Main(): Waited and joined with %d threads. Final value of count = %d. Done.\n",
            NUM_THREADS, count);

    /* Clean up and exit */
    pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&count_mutex);
    pthread_cond_destroy(&count_threshold_cv);
    pthread_exit (NULL);
}
```

How to use mutex in program2 (second.c) to access shared variable . I am using gcc under linux . Any help/pointer will highly appreciated.

Comment: note: "it is working fine." - well, it's multithreading, so that doesn't mean much. do a lot of tests, or use a tool like `valgrind` to detect race conditions.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath to prevent critical section I am using mutex.I run the program(first.c), it gives almost same results most of the time. I think to execute alternate threads in a proper sequence I need to use either semaphore or shared memory. Am I right ?

Comment: Your second process going to have the same image i.e. fork without execl or have different code ? First case - you don't need anything special, but you'd better change your mutex with semaphore since linux pthread mutex - is futex. Second case require mutex  in the shared memory as well as many additional IPC specific things. So you'd better use some library for IPC in this case, like dbus for example.